# Change & animate a text color between two values using Bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'd like to animate a text between two colors using [BlocBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html) instead of a Stateful Widget

This is how I am doing it using a Stateful widget

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation animation;
  Color color;

  @override
  @mustCallSuper
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller=AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5)
    );
    animation=ColorTween(begin:Colors.red,end: Colors.white).animate(controller);

    animation.addListener((){
      setState(() {
        color=animation.value;
      });
    });

    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
home:Scaffold(
        body:Center(child:Text("HELLO!!!",textScaleFactor:3,style: TextStyle(color: color),))));
  }
}
```

I need an animated transition between the two colors so I can't just use :

```
    BlocBuilder<SubjectBloc, SubjectState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Text(
          _label,
          style: TextStyle.labelSmallRegular.copyWith(
              color: state.value
                  ? Color(0xFF2EFFFF)
                  : Color(0xFF61557C),
              ),
        );
```

Comment: How about animatedTextKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supposed to look at this class : [AnimatedDefaultTextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedDefaultTextStyle-class.html)

more explain is available at this [article](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-animateddefaulttextstyle-in-flutter-988c0c6c66a3)

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 210,
  child: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
    curve: Curves.bounceOut,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: _fontSize,
      color: _color,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/logo.png',
          height: _height,
          width: 280,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        const Text("Flutter Dev's"),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```